# Open a new row on button click

Tags: html, angular

I have created an angular form in which user can select time from datepicker and there are multiple dropdowns trough which time can be selected but i want a 'plus' button in front of that row which if clicked will open another row exactly under the first row so that user can add other times and dates. I am making use of Nebular theme

Here is a picture[image]

Here is my form code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="addTimes()" #form="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Course</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <nb-select selected="1" name="name" [(ngModel)]="schedule.course" fullWidth>
                <nb-option *ngFor="let x of courses" [value]="x.name">{{x.name}}</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="label col-sm-3 form-control-label">Class Times</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input nbInput
              placeholder="Form Picker"
              [nbDatepicker]="formpicker" fullWidth name="date" [(ngModel)]="schedule.date">
              <nb-datepicker #formpicker ></nb-datepicker>
              From
              <nb-select selected="0" name="hour" [(ngModel)]="schedule.hour" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <nb-option value="0">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="1">1</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="2">2</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="3">3</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="4">4</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="5">5</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="6">6</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="7">7</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="8">8</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="9">9</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="10">10</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="11">11</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="12">12</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
              <nb-select selected="1" name="minute" [(ngModel)]="schedule.minute">
                <nb-option value="1">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="00">00</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="15">15</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="30">30</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="45">45</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
              <nb-select selected="1" name="timeofday" [(ngModel)]="schedule.timeofday">
                <nb-option value="1">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="AM">AM</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="PM">PM</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
              To 
              <nb-select selected="0" name="tohour" [(ngModel)]="schedule.tohour">
                <nb-option value="0">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="1">1</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="2">2</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="3">3</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="4">4</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="5">5</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="6">6</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="7">7</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="8">8</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="9">9</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="10">10</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="11">11</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="12">12</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
              <nb-select selected="1" name="tominute" [(ngModel)]="schedule.tominute">
                <nb-option value="1">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="00">00</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="15">15</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="30">30</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="45">45</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
              <nb-select selected="1" name="totimeofday" [(ngModel)]="schedule.totimeofday">
                <nb-option value="1">--</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="AM">AM</nb-option>
                <nb-option value="PM">PM</nb-option>
              </nb-select>
            </div>      
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
              <button type="submit" nbButton status="primary">Add Time</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: It will easy with FormArray!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i want to add this whole code in another form where there are other fields too. I have never used form array and also i have to bind all the data with one data transfer object which is `schedule`

Comment: @ahsan nissar - I think you have to do this with FormArray

Comment: @AbolfazLR any helping link? and also i will be adding this whole row in another form where there are other fields like name, email etc so are you sure that form array will be helpful there?

Comment: Check angular Reactive Forms official docs for formArray description. You might encapsulate your whole form (formArray + name, email...) into a formGroup (from reactive form docs too)

Comment: @GérômeGrignon okay i'll see what i can with formarray and will might post my answer tomorrow or maybe i'll edit my question if ran into any problem

Comment: Check the FormArray example here : https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/basics-reactive-forms-in-angular/ (consider the phones formArray as your datepicker info)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can achieve that by using `[ngModelGroup]`

we assume having a model `LabelCalss`

```
export interface LabelCalss {
 label?: string;
}
```

try this:

in your app.component.ts:

```
 formValue: any;

 tags: LabelCalss[] = [
   { label: "important" },
   { label: "difficult" }
 ]

 onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
   let tags = Object.keys(f.value).map(item => {
     return f.value[item];
   });
   this.formValue = tags;
   console.log(tags);
   // Object.keys because the new indexes are string
 }

 addNewRow() {
   this.tags.push({})
 }
```

and in your app.component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">

  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let x of tags; index as i" [ngModelGroup]="i">
    <input name="label"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="x.label">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

<button (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-success mt-5 mb-5">Add New Row</button>

<pre style="background-color:#ddd">
  {{tags|json}}
</pre>

<pre style="background-color:#eee">
  Submitted Object:
  {{formValue|json}}
</pre>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ask7bg)**

Comment: That's also an interesting way. I am trying to make it work with formarray for now however i will try this method too. if it worked i'll mark it correct